# Combine two DateTimes

Tags: sql

In SQL I have the following code fragment :

```
DECLARE 
@DayPart as datetime,
@TimePart as datetime   

SET @DayPart='2012-01-10 00:00:00.000'
SET @TimePart='2012-08-30 15:41:10.403'
```

Now I Need :

```
 '2012-01-10 15:41:10.403'
```

How can I get it?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DayPart,111) + ' ' +  
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@TimePart,108);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get **@DayPart** in `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format and **@TimePart** in `'HH:MI:SS:MMM(24H)'` format and concatenate two strings.

Try this

```
SELECT 
     CONVERT(char(10), @DayPart,126) + ' ' + 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @TimePart, 114)
```

More on SQL Server date formatting

[SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL2K8;

```
select @DayPart + cast(@TimePart as time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DayPart,102),'.','-') + ' ' +  
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@TimePart,108);
```

**[Other Date Formatting](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)**

But if you are using SQL Server 2008+

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, @DayPart) + ' ' + CONVERT(time, @TimePart)
```